# Docker service not starting after installation on Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: ubuntu, docker

I'm having trouble getting docker up and running on Ubuntu 15.10 as per the instructions [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/linux/ubuntulinux/).

After doing a `sudo apt-get install docker-engine` I get the following:

```
Setting up docker-engine (1.10.2-0~wily) ...
Job for docker.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status docker.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
invoke-rc.d: initscript docker, action "start" failed.
```

Which shows that the docker service is not starting after installation. I ran the following commands for more insight:

`systemctl status docker.service -l`:

```
docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/docker.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
  Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d
           └─ubuntu.conf
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2016-03-01 12:55:45 SAST; 3min 26s ago
     Docs: https://docs.docker.com
  Process: 2073 ExecStart=/usr/bin/docker -d -H fd:// $DOCKER_OPTS (code=exited, status=125)
 Main PID: 2073 (code=exited, status=125)

Mar 01 12:55:45 lodewyk-Vostro-3560 systemd[1]: Starting Docker Application Container Engine...
Mar 01 12:55:45 lodewyk-Vostro-3560 docker[2073]: flag provided but not defined: -d
Mar 01 12:55:45 lodewyk-Vostro-3560 docker[2073]: See '/usr/bin/docker --help'.
Mar 01 12:55:45 lodewyk-Vostro-3560 systemd[1]: docker.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=125/n/a
Mar 01 12:55:45 lodewyk-Vostro-3560 systemd[1]: Failed to start Docker Application Container Engine.
Mar 01 12:55:45 lodewyk-Vostro-3560 systemd[1]: docker.service: Unit entered failed state.
Mar 01 12:55:45 lodewyk-Vostro-3560 systemd[1]: docker.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

`journalctl -xe`:

```
-- Unit docker.service has begun starting up.
Mar 01 12:55:45 lodewyk-Vostro-3560 docker[2073]: flag provided but not defined: -d
Mar 01 12:55:45 lodewyk-Vostro-3560 docker[2073]: See '/usr/bin/docker --help'.
Mar 01 12:55:45 lodewyk-Vostro-3560 systemd[1]: docker.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=
Mar 01 12:55:45 lodewyk-Vostro-3560 systemd[1]: Failed to start Docker Application Container Engine.
-- Subject: Unit docker.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit docker.service has failed.
-- 
-- The result is failed.
Mar 01 12:55:45 lodewyk-Vostro-3560 systemd[1]: docker.service: Unit entered failed state.
Mar 01 12:55:45 lodewyk-Vostro-3560 systemd[1]: docker.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

Starting the daemon manually seems to work fine:
`sudo docker daemon -D`:

```
DEBU[0000] docker group found. gid: 999                 
DEBU[0000] Server created for HTTP on unix (/var/run/docker.sock) 
DEBU[0000] Using default logging driver json-file       
INFO[0000] [graphdriver] using prior storage driver "aufs" 
DEBU[0000] Using graph driver aufs                      
INFO[0000] Graph migration to content-addressability took 0.00 seconds 
DEBU[0000] Option DefaultDriver: bridge                 
DEBU[0000] Option DefaultNetwork: bridge                
INFO[0000] Firewalld running: false                     
DEBU[0000] /sbin/iptables, [--wait -t nat -D PREROUTING -m addrtype --dst-type LOCAL -j DOCKER] 
DEBU[0000] /sbin/iptables, [--wait -t nat -D OUTPUT -m addrtype --dst-type LOCAL ! --dst 127.0.0.0/8 -j DOCKER] 
DEBU[0000] /sbin/iptables, [--wait -t nat -D OUTPUT -m addrtype --dst-type LOCAL -j DOCKER] 
DEBU[0000] /sbin/iptables, [--wait -t nat -D PREROUTING] 
DEBU[0000] /sbin/iptables, [--wait -t nat -D OUTPUT]    
DEBU[0000] /sbin/iptables, [--wait -t nat -F DOCKER]    
DEBU[0000] /sbin/iptables, [--wait -t nat -X DOCKER]    
DEBU[0000] /sbin/iptables, [--wait -t filter -F DOCKER] 
DEBU[0000] /sbin/iptables, [--wait -t filter -X DOCKER] 
DEBU[0000] /sbin/iptables, [--wait -t filter -F DOCKER-ISOLATION] 
DEBU[0000] /sbin/iptables, [--wait -t filter -X DOCKER-ISOLATION] 
DEBU[0000] /sbin/iptables, [--wait -t nat -n -L DOCKER] 
DEBU[0000] /sbin/iptables, [--wait -t nat -N DOCKER]    
DEBU[0000] /sbin/iptables, [--wait -t filter -n -L DOCKER] 
DEBU[0000] /sbin/iptables, [--wait -t filter -n -L DOCKER-ISOLATION] 
DEBU[0000] /sbin/iptables, [--wait -t filter -C DOCKER-ISOLATION -j RETURN] 
DEBU[0000] /sbin/iptables, [--wait -I DOCKER-ISOLATION -j RETURN] 
DEBU[0000] Registering ipam driver: "default"           
DEBU[0000] releasing IPv4 pools from network bridge (4be0f7c661962b7f6a6463d5a5497eff6298b7989a952c3bb84704f2dad97a82) 
DEBU[0000] ReleaseAddress(LocalDefault/172.17.0.0/16, 172.17.0.1) 
DEBU[0000] ReleasePool(LocalDefault/172.17.0.0/16)      
INFO[0000] Default bridge (docker0) is assigned with an IP address 172.17.0.0/16. Daemon option --bip can be used to set a preferred IP address 
DEBU[0000] Allocating IPv4 pools for network bridge (409fea567a03f72bc33f1cbe0fe82b2e0d7969bc8471e5741da91c7de0289e89) 
DEBU[0000] RequestPool(LocalDefault, 172.17.0.0/16, , map[], false) 
DEBU[0000] RequestAddress(LocalDefault/172.17.0.0/16, 172.17.0.1, map[RequestAddressType:com.docker.network.gateway]) 
DEBU[0000] /sbin/iptables, [--wait -t nat -C POSTROUTING -s 172.17.0.0/16 ! -o docker0 -j MASQUERADE] 
DEBU[0000] /sbin/iptables, [--wait -t nat -C DOCKER -i docker0 -j RETURN] 
DEBU[0000] /sbin/iptables, [--wait -t nat -I DOCKER -i docker0 -j RETURN] 
DEBU[0000] /sbin/iptables, [--wait -D FORWARD -i docker0 -o docker0 -j DROP] 
DEBU[0000] /sbin/iptables, [--wait -t filter -C FORWARD -i docker0 -o docker0 -j ACCEPT] 
DEBU[0000] /sbin/iptables, [--wait -t filter -C FORWARD -i docker0 ! -o docker0 -j ACCEPT] 
DEBU[0000] /sbin/iptables, [--wait -t filter -C FORWARD -o docker0 -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT] 
DEBU[0000] /sbin/iptables, [--wait -t nat -C PREROUTING -m addrtype --dst-type LOCAL -j DOCKER] 
DEBU[0000] /sbin/iptables, [--wait -t nat -A PREROUTING -m addrtype --dst-type LOCAL -j DOCKER] 
DEBU[0000] /sbin/iptables, [--wait -t nat -C OUTPUT -m addrtype --dst-type LOCAL -j DOCKER ! --dst 127.0.0.0/8] 
DEBU[0000] /sbin/iptables, [--wait -t nat -A OUTPUT -m addrtype --dst-type LOCAL -j DOCKER ! --dst 127.0.0.0/8] 
DEBU[0000] /sbin/iptables, [--wait -t filter -C FORWARD -o docker0 -j DOCKER] 
DEBU[0000] /sbin/iptables, [--wait -t filter -C FORWARD -o docker0 -j DOCKER] 
DEBU[0000] /sbin/iptables, [--wait -t filter -C FORWARD -j DOCKER-ISOLATION] 
DEBU[0000] /sbin/iptables, [--wait -D FORWARD -j DOCKER-ISOLATION] 
DEBU[0000] /sbin/iptables, [--wait -I FORWARD -j DOCKER-ISOLATION] 
WARN[0000] Your kernel does not support swap memory limit. 
DEBU[0000] Cleaning up old shm/mqueue mounts: start.    
DEBU[0000] Cleaning up old shm/mqueue mounts: done.     
INFO[0000] Daemon has completed initialization          
INFO[0000] Docker daemon                                 commit=c3959b1 execdriver=native-0.2 graphdriver=aufs version=1.10.2
DEBU[0000] Registering routers                          
DEBU[0000] Registering HEAD, /containers/{name:.*}/archive 
DEBU[0000] Registering GET, /containers/json            
DEBU[0000] Registering GET, /containers/{name:.*}/export 
DEBU[0000] Registering GET, /containers/{name:.*}/changes 
DEBU[0000] Registering GET, /containers/{name:.*}/json  
DEBU[0000] Registering GET, /containers/{name:.*}/top   
DEBU[0000] Registering GET, /containers/{name:.*}/logs  
DEBU[0000] Registering GET, /containers/{name:.*}/stats 
DEBU[0000] Registering GET, /containers/{name:.*}/attach/ws 
DEBU[0000] Registering GET, /exec/{id:.*}/json          
DEBU[0000] Registering GET, /containers/{name:.*}/archive 
DEBU[0000] Registering POST, /containers/create         
DEBU[0000] Registering POST, /containers/{name:.*}/kill 
DEBU[0000] Registering POST, /containers/{name:.*}/pause 
DEBU[0000] Registering POST, /containers/{name:.*}/unpause 
DEBU[0000] Registering POST, /containers/{name:.*}/restart 
DEBU[0000] Registering POST, /containers/{name:.*}/start 
DEBU[0000] Registering POST, /containers/{name:.*}/stop 
DEBU[0000] Registering POST, /containers/{name:.*}/wait 
DEBU[0000] Registering POST, /containers/{name:.*}/resize 
DEBU[0000] Registering POST, /containers/{name:.*}/attach 
DEBU[0000] Registering POST, /containers/{name:.*}/copy 
DEBU[0000] Registering POST, /containers/{name:.*}/exec 
DEBU[0000] Registering POST, /exec/{name:.*}/start      
DEBU[0000] Registering POST, /exec/{name:.*}/resize     
DEBU[0000] Registering POST, /containers/{name:.*}/rename 
DEBU[0000] Registering POST, /containers/{name:.*}/update 
DEBU[0000] Registering PUT, /containers/{name:.*}/archive 
DEBU[0000] Registering DELETE, /containers/{name:.*}    
DEBU[0000] Registering GET, /images/json                
DEBU[0000] Registering GET, /images/search              
DEBU[0000] Registering GET, /images/get                 
DEBU[0000] Registering GET, /images/{name:.*}/get       
DEBU[0000] Registering GET, /images/{name:.*}/history   
DEBU[0000] Registering GET, /images/{name:.*}/json      
DEBU[0000] Registering POST, /commit                    
DEBU[0000] Registering POST, /images/create             
DEBU[0000] Registering POST, /images/load               
DEBU[0000] Registering POST, /images/{name:.*}/push     
DEBU[0000] Registering POST, /images/{name:.*}/tag      
DEBU[0000] Registering DELETE, /images/{name:.*}        
DEBU[0000] Registering GET, /networks                   
DEBU[0000] Registering GET, /networks/{id:.*}           
DEBU[0000] Registering POST, /networks/create           
DEBU[0000] Registering POST, /networks/{id:.*}/connect  
DEBU[0000] Registering POST, /networks/{id:.*}/disconnect 
DEBU[0000] Registering DELETE, /networks/{id:.*}        
DEBU[0000] Registering OPTIONS, /{anyroute:.*}          
DEBU[0000] Registering GET, /_ping                      
DEBU[0000] Registering GET, /events                     
DEBU[0000] Registering GET, /info                       
DEBU[0000] Registering GET, /version                    
DEBU[0000] Registering POST, /auth                      
DEBU[0000] Registering GET, /volumes                    
DEBU[0000] Registering GET, /volumes/{name:.*}          
DEBU[0000] Registering POST, /volumes/create            
DEBU[0000] Registering DELETE, /volumes/{name:.*}       
DEBU[0000] Registering POST, /build                     
INFO[0000] API listen on /var/run/docker.sock
```

`docker version`:

```
Client:
 Version:      1.10.2
 API version:  1.22
 Go version:   go1.5.3
 Git commit:   c3959b1
 Built:        Mon Feb 22 21:40:35 2016
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
Server:
 Version:      1.10.2
 API version:  1.22
 Go version:   go1.5.3
 Git commit:   c3959b1
 Built:        Mon Feb 22 21:40:35 2016
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
```

`docker info`:

```
Containers: 0
 Running: 0
 Paused: 0
 Stopped: 0
Images: 0
Server Version: 1.10.2
Storage Driver: aufs
 Root Dir: /var/lib/docker/aufs
 Backing Filesystem: extfs
 Dirs: 0
 Dirperm1 Supported: true
Execution Driver: native-0.2
Logging Driver: json-file
Plugins: 
 Volume: local
 Network: bridge null host
Kernel Version: 4.2.0-30-generic
Operating System: Ubuntu 15.10
OSType: linux
Architecture: x86_64
CPUs: 8
Total Memory: 15.54 GiB
Name: lodewyk-Vostro-3560
ID: Q54Q:Y6EV:M5GL:LJMZ:Z5Q6:2U2U:QHFK:UL5O:3FF6:PUOR:Z7IQ:WKME
Debug mode (server): true
 File Descriptors: 11
 Goroutines: 30
 System Time: 2016-03-01T13:14:30.859976076+02:00
 EventsListeners: 0
 Init SHA1: aa0828af5f3b48c398d9231a4c1aba310a01561d
 Init Path: /usr/lib/docker/dockerinit
 Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
WARNING: No swap limit support
```

I've tried removing Docker completely as well as removing the `/var/lib/docker` files and reinstalling. I've also added myself to the docker group `sudo usermod -aG docker <username>`> I've also ensured that the `DOCKER_HOST` variable is unset.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Is this on local machine? I encountered same error where the Docker daemon not running properly on a VPS and found out that I need to restart the system. It could be specific to my distro (not Ubuntu) or maybe it is required to restart due to some drivers stuff. Try a reboot if you can.

Comment: I'm getting a slightly different error case (docker-engine is failing to start but it never exits and just thrashes my hard drive) trying to install this version (1.10.2-0~wily) of the package. So there's something wrong with it. Reverting to a previous version with ` sudo apt-get install docker-engine=1.9.1-0~wily` was my workaround solution.

Comment: Reverting back to a previous version fixed it. This was done as part of an upgrade exercise that we're running (we were on 1.6.2 which worked fine).